# Which is faster : defaultdict in python or libcpp.map in cython?

Tags: optimization, cythonize

I am trying to optimize a function which store words and its count. Python implementation is quite slow as of now. I am trying to cythonize the function. What other alternatives do we have in cython corresponding to defaultdict ?